# Appdynamics Instrumentation on Jboss Fuse ESB 6.3

Tags: jboss, esb, instrumentation, jbossfuse, appdynamics

We have a JBoss fuse ESB instance Running Version 6.3.0. With this, Installed as a Service using tanuki wrapper. When passing the javaagent Argument The Application (hawtio)Breaks. we have tried passing the argument in the following files:

> JBOSSHOME/bin/karaf/
>
> JBOSSHOME/etc/jboss-fuse-wrapper.conf
>
> -javaagent:/agenthome/javaagent.jar

The JVM Loads the argument when it is passing in the wrapper.conf, but as mentioned before the application is not working when the argument is loaded in the JVM.

have anyone instrumented JBoss Fuse ESB with app dynamics before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
wrapper.java.additional.6=-javaagent:C://agent//javaagent.jar
```

into  `wrapper.conf` file.

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Tanuki+Service+Wrapper+Settings